# How do I fix the tab “Access Control” not opening in Keychain Access?

Tags: keychain

In [Keychain Access](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH20117?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US), I have some items where I cannot open the tab “Access Control”. When I double-click one of these items to open a window on it, the window opens with the tab “Attributes” selected; when I try to click the tab header “Access Control”, the header animates but the tab itself does not open. The tab “Attributes” remains selected.

I am not sure whether it’s related, but in Console I see repeated entries for Keychain Access that say: `CSSM Exception: -2147413737 CSSMERR_DL_DATASTORE_DOESNOT_EXIST`. There are also a lot of entries that say: `CSSM Exception: -2147413750 CSSMERR_DL_INVALID_FIELD_NAME`.

How can I fix the items so I can open the tab “Access Control” again? I am not sure whether the keychain itself is broken, is there some Terminal command I can use to verify (and repair) it? Or does “Access Control” rely on some other data store that may need repair?

Comment: I tried whether moving the items to another keychain (by drag&drop) would help. Yes and no: when in the other keychain, I could open “Access Control” on the items, but when I dragged them back to the original keychain, I no longer could. I also observed odd behavior with the count of items at the bottom of the Keychain Access window: I moved 4 items, but the count went down by 5; it went up again by 5 after dragging the 4 items back. I reverted the keychain to a backup after this, because for now I do not want to wind up breaking it more than it already is by fiddling with it too much.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting category to "My Certificates" at the left bottom of "KeyChain Access" window. Then find the certificate, expend it to get the key and try changing "Access Control" on that one.